# Playstore will approve the app if i implemented multiple payment gateways in my application?

Tags: android, google-play, payment-gateway

I have created one application which is having 4 payment gateways inside for making the payment. At a time only one payment gate way will active based on some settings in my server.

My doubt is there any problem with this number of payment gateways in the app for approval in playstore?

Answer (score 0):

There is no checking or reviewing the app on play store.it is not IOS where they take 7-20 days for reviewing the app.it is just 2-3 hour game on play store to successfully upload APK.

Comment: so can we think it is automated process?